# Trying to create a trigger in SQL server that converts and inserts an xml string

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005

Have created this trigger

It completes successfully and enters into the right tables, however when it all processes through on the table that it inserts into the table the Long Message section of the trigger has "NULL" inside in there.

It is not often that I look at SQL really. The actual part of the script that converts the data to XML string on its own works and makes a string. However when it is in the trigger it doesn't populate anything.

///////////////////////////////////////////

```
USE [SysproCompanyP]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[trig_DNIP]    Script Date: 28/09/2015 11:25:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


--=======================================
-- Author       : Thomas Mullins
-- Create date  : 02/09/2015
-- Description  : Email event on a dispatch note being printed
-- Update
-- Update
--=======================================

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_DNIP]
      ON [dbo].[MdnMaster]
      AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN 

DECLARE @ConstCompany AS CHAR(1)
DECLARE @SourceCompanyFull AS CHAR(40)

DECLARE @DispatchNote AS CHAR(15)
DECLARE @SalesOrder AS CHAR(6)
DECLARE @CustomerName AS CHAR(30)
DECLARE @Customer AS CHAR(7)
DECLARE @var_LongMessage AS CHAR (255)



SET @SourceCompanyFull = DB_NAME()
SET @ConstCompany = UPPER(RIGHT(RTRIM(@SourceCompanyFull),1))

IF @ConstCompany = 'S'
BEGIN 
   SET @ConstCompany = '0'
END


SELECT 
    @DispatchNote = RTRIM(DispatchNote), 
    @SalesOrder = RTRIM(SalesOrder),
    @CustomerName = RTRIM(CustomerName), 
    @Customer = RTRIM(Customer)
FROM INSERTED 


SET NOCOUNT ON; 

IF @Customer in ('CN01PIO', 'CN01WUH') --AND datepart(yyyy, @CreationDate) = datepart(yyyy, getdate() and datepart(mm, @CreationDate = datepart(mm, @CreationDate) = datepart (mm,getdate()) and datepart(dd, @CreationDate) = datepart(dd, getdate()
BEGIN 

    SET @var_LongMessage = (SELECT (STUFF((
               SELECT ',  ' + RTRIM(WRL.StockCode) + ' ' + RTRIM(WRL.Job) + '     '
               FROM SysproCompanyP.dbo.MdnDetailLot (nolock) AS MDL 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN SysproCompanyP.dbo.WipReservedLots (nolock) AS WRL on WRL.Lot = MDL.Lot 
               WHERE MDL.DispatchNote = RTRIM(@DispatchNote)
               GROUP BY WRL.StockCode, WRL.Job 
               FOR XML PATH('')
               ), 1, 2, '')
            ))

INSERT INTO [SysproCompanyC].[dbo].[EmailEvents]
       ([SourceCompany]         ,[SourceCompanyFull]    ,[ParentValue]          ,[CFFName]          ,[CFFData]  ,[TxtFileExtension]  ,[DateEntered]    ,[LongMessage])
VALUES 
       (@ConstCompany          ,@SourceCompanyFull    ,@SalesOrder            ,@Customer      ,@DispatchNote    ,'DNIP'                ,GETDATE()       ,@var_LongMessage)

INSERT INTO [Piolax_Logging].[dbo].[EventLogging]   ([Company],[EventType],[Source],[Annotation],[NumberOfRecords],[DateTime])
        VALUES (@ConstCompany           ,'INFO'           ,'[trig_DNIP]'           ,'Dispatch Note Printed  '  + @DispatchNote + @ConstCompany + @SourceCompanyFull + @SalesOrder  + @Customer + 'DNIP' + HOST_NAME(),1           ,GETDATE())
END 




END
```

If anybody could give my any info that would be great, thanks.

Comment: Trigger fires per entire statement, not row by row

Comment: **Disclaimer** Triggers are often a bad idea, they are good for logging but if only its a simple operation. They are also horrible for debug. Also putting BL inside the DB is a bad practice. 1) Check if the trigger is firing. 2) Check if it's really inserting by just insering plain text in a test table. 3) Check if another trigger is impairing you,

Comment: Hi, I have read that they can be a bad idea too. Usually I have simple ones that are straight forward. However with this I need to link 3 separate rows into one XML string.

Comment: I tried adding it to the stored procedure that processes it from the table that the trigger enters it into. However this just looped and would not populate. The trigger is definitely firing it populates all the data EXCEPT for the xml string, in the field it just has "NULL". On its own the script runs fine though.

Comment: The Select from INserted into the variables will result in them having the last record in the result set. It's not exevuted per record.